# Plotly Map show a MultiPolygon Python

Tags: python, maps, plotly-python

I have problem when I try to show the map using plotly python, and the result is an area that I don't need, How can I delete this area? or How can I configure the options for only showing the locations? My code is the next:

```
ctrl_zone = json.load(open("control_zones.geojson","r")
for feature in ctrl_zone['features']:
       feature['id'] = feature['properties']['gerencia']
```

This part I have a DataFrame with the data of control_zones like:

```
       id    value
 0   ctrl_1   10        
 1   ctrl_2   20          
 2   ctrl_3   30
```

The configuration of the plotly choropleth is the follow:

```
fig = px.choropleth(df_gerencia, locations = 'id', geojson = ctrl_zone, color = 'value')
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations",visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Finally the result is:

[Without zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbuRQ.png)
[When I try to do a zoom of the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkMOA.png)

Thanks for yours comments

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to what you linked in your post. In my case, it turned out that mapshaper, which I was using to convert from .shp to geojson was using a newer standard that is not implemented in D3, and therefore not this Plotly map.

When I used the o=gj2008 flag in mapshaper, I was then able to correctly map the geojson. This link was helpful: https://community.plotly.com/t/choropleth-map-not-working-with-my-geojson-data/43934/2